# DevExpress LookupEdit

Tags: c#

When working with data imported from the database, I'm wondering if I can only put 2, if it's possible to do more than 3 If possible, I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to do it.

For example, create direct data table and do more than three things when working (defined by ex fullname and divided by firstname and secondname)

//This code contains only two values

```
private void XtraForm3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TB_CO_HIST Hist = new TB_CO_HIST();

        custType.Properties.DataSource = Hist.SelectClassItemLoopUp("10", "B001008"); 
        custType.Properties.DisplayMember = "분류명";
        custType.Properties.ValueMember = "분류코드";          


        DisplayData();     
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.